# Distributing different objects to 4 groups

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

The task is to find how many possibilities are for sets $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4 \subseteq  
 [n]$ so that $A_1\bigcap A_2\bigcap A_3\bigcap A_4 = \emptyset$ and $A_1\bigcup A_2\bigcup A_3\bigcup A_4 = [n]$

My attempt:

First i go on every element of $[n]$ and decide if it's in $A_1$ or not, which accumulates to $2^n$. then I do the same for $A_2$ and $A_3$. After that, I add all the elements that aren't picked for any of the first 3 groups to $A_4$.

All together is $2^n * 2^n * 2^n = 2^{3n}$.

However, I still think I count something double times so I'm not sure about that answer.

Comment: What is $[n]$? ${}$

Comment: Your answer is correct, i do not see anything wrong with it. :)

Comment: $[n] =${1,2,3,4,....n}

Comment: Are you sure it's right? Am I not counting twice the option $\emptyset$,{1} ,$\emptyset$,{1}  for lets say n=1?

Comment: @Shaun $[n]$ is an $n$-element set of distinct natural numbers.  Some authors use it to refer to $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, other authors use it to refer to $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$.  Most times it appears, the distinction between the two does not matter as the only thing that mattered was that it was an $n$ element set and the result remains the same regardless of whether it started at $0$ or ended at $n$.

Comment: Can the sets be empty? You might want to look up partitions.

Comment: Yes they can be empty

Answer (score 3):

Notice that each element of $[n]$ must satisfy the following two things:

- It is in at least one of $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$
- It is not in at least one of $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$

This is to guarantee that the union of $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ is the entirety of $[n]$ and the intersection of $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ is empty.

This implies that each element of $[n]$ can be uniquely described by one of the $2^{4}-2$ length $4$ binary strings with at least one $0$ and at least one $1$ corresponding to which of $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ the element is in.

We have then, every collection of $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ can be described uniquely by a sequence of such length $4$ binary strings where each has at least one $0$ and at least one $1$.

By multiplication principle then we have as a final count of

$$(2^4-2)^n=14^n$$

possible collections of $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$

Comment: Nice answer. I thought about it too just with the multiplication principle and not binary strings.

Comment: Can you solve it if the sets are not indexed?